# Stripping \r\n from a line

Tags: python

I want to strip the ending \r\n for a line, examples of the line:

```
abc \r\n
abc \r
abc \n
```

I want it to remain as
   "abc "

what I do now

```
line=line.strip('\n')
line=line.strip('\r')
line=line.strip('\n')
```

is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use one `str.strip()` call:

```
line = line.strip('\r\n')
```

This removes *both* characters, in whatever order. The argument to `str.strip()` is treated as a *set* of characters, not one longer string:

```
>>> 'foo bar\r\n\n\r\n\r\n\r\r\r'.strip('\r\n')
'foo bar'
```

Since you'd expect these lines to only have the characters at the *end* of each line, you can limit the stripping work to just that side with `str.rstrip`:

```
line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
```

Comment: May be `rstrip` is better, since the OP want to strip these characters at the end of the line.

Comment: @WKPlus: yeah, and save Python some work (testing if the first character is in the stripped set).

Answer (score 2):

If the line is ending with \r\n you can strip-right.

```
line = line.rstrip(' \r\n')
```